# Grammar related to "not only ... but also..."

Tags: grammar

I know when using ***not only ... but also ...*** we should follow parallelism. Ex:  ***not only cats but also dogs***, or ***not only run but also jump***. However, I am confused which of the followings is correct and is it necessary to put comma before the ***but***?

1. Generally, a system is required to be not only stable but also stable by some margin of safety.
2. Generally, a system is required not only be stable but also be stable by some margin of safety.

Comment: No 2 is missing a "to".

Comment: As @KillingTime said, #2 needs "to" after "required", or better after both "not only" and "but also". You could avoid the question and, in my opinion, improve the sentence with: "Generally a system is required to be stable, not just barely but with some margin of safety."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a real parallelism, as the second part of this structure does not offer another element, but simply adds a circumstance to the already existing element. ***Not only*** can also be used before the verb. To emphasise that this is an addition and not a parallelism, I would say:

> Generally, a system is ***not only** required* **to** be ***merely*** stable,  but <del>also</del> be stable by some margin of safety. *[you omitted this "to" in your second example]*

[This article](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/not-only-but-also/) shows the way this *correlating conjunction* is used and says that not all grammarians are so strict about it being used for parallelism only.

Comment: thanks! So 1 is correct and in 2 can be modified using your suggestion, is it correct?

Comment: In numer 1 I would omit _also_ to avoid ambiguity.